# Placing two elements inline

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am attempting to place an `iframe` and `img` inline in a `div`. The code that I have posted puts the `img` below the `iframe`. I have tried to `position` and `float` the elements but nothing seems to work. I have also checked out other posts on SO, but nothing seems to work. I am willing to start from scratch if required.

I would be grateful if someone could point out my error and show me the corrections to make to get this to work. I have looked at other posts but nothing seems to be working.

Thank you.

```css
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1080px;
  }
}
.hero-unit {
  background-color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #252525;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.hero-unit img {
  display: inline-block;
}
.fp-block {
  padding: 5px !important;
  padding: 0;
}
/*** CUSTOM CODE FOR YOUTUBE VIDEO DISPLAY ***/

.inner {
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
  margin: 0;
}
.holder {
  height: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hero-unit fp-block">
    <div id="ut-wrap">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="holder">
          <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_VRXrp_AfMM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you set up a JSFiddle demonstrating your problem?

Comment: I just created a JSFiddle and I can see both elements inline on the same div.Maybe the issues is that you are using a `media-quary` which tilts it for your monitor?

Comment: Zombie I have taken the media query out and it still showing the images stacked not inline. thanks

Comment: Post the relevant code in a fiddle.

Comment: I solved your problem easily using `Bootstrap`. Is using `Bootstrap` ok with you?

Comment: @Zombie I am using bootstrap v2.2.1

Comment: @Zombie could you post the solution please

Comment: @user1532468 If you have a new problem please create a new question rather than adding additional queries to the current one. Doing so can lead to confusion for other users who find your question and can cause answers to lose significance even if they address the original problem. You are also more likely to get fresh answers to a new question. I've rolled back your question to remove the new update.

Answer (score 2):

## The problem

The issue is that `.inner` has a `width` of `49%` which is pushing the image onto a new line. This can be seen if you add a background color and height to `.inner`.

```css
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1080px;
  }
}
.hero-unit {
  background-color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #252525;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.hero-unit img {
  display: inline-block;
}
.fp-block {
  padding: 5px !important;
  padding: 0;
}
/*** CUSTOM CODE FOR YOUTUBE VIDEO DISPLAY ***/

.inner {
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}
.holder {
  height: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
iframe {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hero-unit fp-block">
    <div id="ut-wrap">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="holder">
          <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_VRXrp_AfMM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## How to fix

### Option 1

Add `whitespace: nowrap;` to `.holder` to stop the image from being able to wrap onto the next line

```css
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1080px;
  }
}
.hero-unit {
  background-color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #252525;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.hero-unit img {
  display: inline-block;
}
.fp-block {
  padding: 5px !important;
  padding: 0;
}
/*** CUSTOM CODE FOR YOUTUBE VIDEO DISPLAY ***/

.inner {
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
  margin: 0;
}
.holder {
  height: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hero-unit fp-block">
    <div id="ut-wrap">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="holder">
          <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_VRXrp_AfMM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Option 2

Set a larger `width` on `.inner`.

```css
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1080px;
  }
}
.hero-unit {
  background-color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #252525;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.hero-unit img {
  display: inline-block;
}
.fp-block {
  padding: 5px !important;
  padding: 0;
}
/*** CUSTOM CODE FOR YOUTUBE VIDEO DISPLAY ***/

.inner {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.holder {
  height: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hero-unit fp-block">
    <div id="ut-wrap">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="holder">
          <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_VRXrp_AfMM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First option does nothing. If I increase .inner width to 100% this gives me full width iframe with img under. thanks

Comment: @user1532468 Hmm, that's interesting because the first option should ensure the two elements are always on the same line regardless of screen width. Does the Stack snippet in my answer wrap the image onto the second line for you?

Comment: If I look at your code snippet, I see youtube on the left and 150 x 150 next to it

Comment: @user1532468 If it's working in the snippet but not on your site it is possible that there is another factor at play. Are you able to create a JSFiddle that reproduces the issue so I can see what the issue is?

Comment: Got to got out for a while so will try later. BTW I am using bootstrap v2.2.2.1 if that helps at all. thanks.

Comment: Were you ever able to reproduce the issue or did this solve your problem @user1532468?